# WinAPI получить время создания pagefile.sys

Tags: winapi

Как получить время создания файла pagefile.sys с помощью WinAPI?
Из MSDN:

> `BOOL WINAPI GetFileTime(_In_ HANDLE hFile,......`
>    The handle must have
>   been created using the CreateFile function with the GENERIC_READ
>   access right.

Но попытка HANDLE WINAPI CreateFile возвращает:

> GetLastError 0x20 - The process cannot access the file because it is
>   being used by another process.

Answer (score 1):

`FindFirstFile()` и поле `WIN32_FIND_DATA.ftCreationTime` попробуйте...

Comment: Премного благодарен. Способ работает.